How to go to IIS namespace in Powershell
I am using System.Management.Automation dll to create powershell and invoke some commands.
The commands require that I am start in IIS namespace PS IIS:\ >:
New-item AppPools\TestAppPool

I execute the commands like this:
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
while (reader2.ReadLine() != null)
{
    ps.AddCommand(reader2.ReadLine());
    ps.Invoke();
}

currently the commands don't execute when I call Invoke. So how to change the powershell namespace to IIS?

By running Set-Location IIS: after module import

If you just need to navigate to a specific directory to execute subsequent commands, use the Set-Location command already mentioned by community member to implement your requirements. What do you mean by the command not being executed when calling invoke()? Are there any error messages?
